# Constant combining in optimizing compilers

Tags: c++, c, gcc, constants, inline

I have a header file containing a lot of small inline functions. Most of them happen to have constant data. Since these functions are performance critical, the way they handle constants becomes important. AFAIK there are two ways to refer to constants:

1) Define them in a separate source file that is later linked with the application.

2) Define the constants in-place.

I would choose the latter way because it's more maintainable. However, the it might be slower if the compiler doesn't optimize thousands of equal constants that are created by inlining.

**The question:**

Will the compiler combine these equal constants? In particular, which of the following methods will be utilized?

1) Combining of equal constants across the compilation unit.
2) Combining of equal constants across the linking module (whole program or library)
3) Combining the constants with *any* static constant data that happens to have the same bit pattern and fulfills the alignment requirements across the compilation unit or whole program.

I use a modern compiler (GCC4.5).

I'm not an expert in assembler, thus I couldn't answer this question myself using several simple tests :)

**EDIT:**

The constants are quite big (most of them at least 16 bytes), so the compiler can't make them immediate values.

**EDIT2:**

**EXAMPLE of the code**

This one uses the constant in-place:

```
float_4 sign(float_4 a)
{
    const __attribute__((aligned(16))) float mask[4] = { //I use a macro for this line
        0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000};
    const int128 mask = load(mask);
    return b_and(a, mask);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Define the constants in-place"? Like `const int i = 5;`?

Comment: Yes. By saying constant I mean any data that is independent from the arguments of the function.

Comment: I'm not an expert on GCC, but most compilers do not combine const literals at all, unless they are string literals. Furthermore, a const literal is usually embedded in code as an immediate value. It's up to the comiler to enforce the const-ness of the value once it's loaded into a memory variable.

Comment: I think you're confused about how using const data affects performance; e.g. in "Since these functions are performance critical, the way they handle constants becomes important." and in "However, the it might be slower if the compiler doesn't optimize thousands of equal constants that are created by inlining."

Comment: BTW, [how enable identical string storage combining in VC++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h227906.aspx)

Comment: @ThomasMcLead.  These constants are pretty bit, most of them are at least 16 bytes. So no way to embed as immediate values (and that would severely limit the performance of the instruction decoders since they're already bottlenecks). And if GCC does not combine constants at all, I'm quite unhappy, because it means lots of manual work.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: No I'm not confused. Actually the question is confusing since it has almost nothing to do with the constness of data (i.e. cost keyword). It's just about how the compiler handles read-only data.

Comment: @jons34yp: Sounds like clarifying the question would really help.  Have a short example?

Comment: @jons34yp Not merging constants would make the program bigger, but how do you envision that making it slower?

Comment: @Jim Balter: If compiler does not merge constants I'd get quite a _lot_ cache misses in performance critical code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) the following option does what you want:

> -fmerge-constants
>   Attempt to merge identical constants (string constants and floating point constants) across compilation units.
>   This option is the default for optimized compilation if the assembler and linker support it. Use -fno-merge-constants to inhibit this behavior.
>   Enabled at levels -O, -O2, -O3, -Os.

Answer (score 2):

If you define constants in your header file like this:

```
int const TEN = 10;
// or
enum { ELEVEN = 11 };
```

That is, not only the constant declaration but the definition as well is visible to the compiler when compiling a translation unit (a .cc source file), then certainly the compiler replaces it with a constant value in the generated code even with no optimizations enabled.

```
[max@truth test]$ cat test.cc
int const TEN = 10; // definition available
extern int const TWELVE; // only declaration

int foo(int x) { return x + TEN; }
int bar(int x) { return x + TWELVE; }

[max@truth test]$ g++ -S -o - test.cc | c++filt | egrep -v " *\."
foo(int):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $10, %eax
    leave
    ret
bar(int):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    TWELVE(%rip), %eax
    addl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    leave
    ret
TEN:
```

Notice how in `foo(int)` it does the addition as `addl $10, %eax`, i.e. TEN constant is replaced with its value. In `bar(int)`, on the other hand, it first does `movl TWELVE(%rip), %eax` to load the value of TWELVE from memory into eax register (the address will be resolved by the linker) and then does the addition `addl -4(%rbp), %eax`.

An optimized version looks like this:

```
[max@truth test]$ g++ -O3 -S -o - test.cc | c++filt | egrep -v " *\."
foo(int):
    leal    10(%rdi), %eax
    ret
bar(int):
    movl    TWELVE(%rip), %eax
    addl    %edi, %eax
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there are general answers to your questions. I give one for C only, the rules for C++ are different.

This depends a lot on the types of your constants. An important class are "integer constant expressions". These can be determined at compile time and in particular be used as values of "integer enumeration constants". Use that whenever you may

```
enum { myFavoriteDimension = 55/2 };
```

For such constants the best thing should usually happen: they are realized as assembler immediates. They don't even have a storage location, are directly written into the assembler and your questions don't even make sense.

For other data types the question is more delicate. Try to enforce that no address of your "const qualified variables" is taken. This can be done with the `register` keyword.

```
register double const something = 5.7;
```

may have the same effect as above.

For composed types (`struct`, `union`, arrays) there is no general answer or method. I have already seen that gcc is able to optimize small arrays (10 elements or so) completely.