# Does concatenation of constants get optimized to the concatenated form at compile time in C#?

Tags: c#, constants, concatenation, obfuscation, disassembly

I have two constants, defined in the same static class:

```
public static class MyConstants {
    public const string ABC = "ABC";
    public const string DEF = "DEF";
}
```

I use them in a combined manner, elsewhere in my application:

```
Console.WriteLine(MyConstants.ABC + MyConstants.DEF);
```

I'm trying to determine if the concatenation is optimized at compile time, resulting in the assembly containing a value of `ABCDEF` at some address when disassembled, or if it stays separate. I followed the instructions on [this MSDN post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-disassembly-window?view=vs-2019) to view the disassembly of my code in a console application and it appears that it is not stored as `ABCDEF`, nor separate as `ABC`, `DEF`:

[image: Disassembly Window]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010216/constant-combining-in-optimizing-compilers) was a good read, but ultimately confused me in relation to my question (*likely due to my lack of C++ knowledge*). I've looked at several other posts and don't really seem to be getting anywhere near the answer.

---

Does C# optimize the concatenation of two constants in the compiled version of an application, any/everywhere that concatenation is used?

**NOTE**: The goal is to further obfuscate the full value of `ABCDEF`, making it harder to find.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmARgFgAoHAZgAJ9KBhSgb1MpcoGMB7AO1moIAZKAZRgI0XAOYFKAXkoAiAIIAhWvIDczVpx4w+gkWMl5ZCgCIBRAGIatLCtQAslALIAKAJSM7rewMoIcFAArhh6cobiUgDUkcaaJL6+OAQAnG6BIWEeCb4AvqR5QA==) and note the instruction `ldstr "ABCDEF"`.

Comment: @madreflection, always around to help lol I should really bookmark that website haha, so that shows me that it was indeed optimized and can be found as `ABCDEF` in the disassembly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: As far as I know, the concatenation of constants results in a compile-time constant.  That's why you can use an expression like `MyConstants.ABC + MyConstants.DEF` in places where a constant is required (for example, within Attributes, or as default values for parameters).  It's the same idea with `const int`s (they add up at compile time)

Comment: The most important sentence in your question is the note at the end. **Do not attempt this sort of security through obscurity**. If you have a secret in your code that must be kept secret *from the person running the code* then you have failed to build a correct threat model and you should stop writing code until you have built a correct threat model.  The .NET security system is explicitly designed to protect *benign users* from *hostile code*; your note implies that you wish to protect *benign code* from *hostile users*, and you will fail to do so.

Comment: @EricLippert thank you for pointing that out! I'd never thought of it that way!

Comment: @タコス: You might want to use [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for that link! It's a good reference point, but note the remark that it shouldn't be used for new development about half way down the page. Thanks again for the reading material though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the concatenated string is [interned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-5.0) see: [.NET-Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z27RaK)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string abcdef = MyConstants.ABC + MyConstants.DEF;
         if(string.IsInterned(abcdef) != null)
        {
            Console.Write("abcdef is interned");
        }
    }
}


public static class MyConstants {
    public const string ABC = "ABC";
    public const string DEF = "DEF";
}
```

I think Jon answers it also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/288802/284240